# How to add a Back button to a NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button

How do I add the back button to a navigation bar? I know there are some related questions but none of them helped. I'm not using storyboard nor did I start with the Master Detail template. Is there a setting to do this? or do you add it by code? if so what code do I need? Any help is appreciated! THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back button will appear by default if you use a navigationController correctly. The ViewControllers should be this

NavigationController > FirstViewController > SecondViewController

You will need to create navigationController and instantiate with firstVC as the root. From firstVC you can push `secondVC` and the back button will be there.

The following placed into appDelegate `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` will load firstVC initially. Place this after you initialize the window...

```
   UIViewController *firstVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"firstVC" bundle:nil];
   // any setupup of firstVC
   UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstVC];
   [self.window setRootViewController:navCon];
```

Then in your firstVC class if you want to push secondVC

in firstVC.m:

```
UIViewController *secondVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: I did this but its still not appearing, i've added the Navigation Controller in the xib, but do i need to do anything else to that?, i mean it gives me no errors but its not showing :/

Comment: The firstVC is the one associated with the xib. the navigation controller (navCon) is never actually seen. It is just a base for the other viewcontroller to be stacked on. If your firstVC is loaded correctly from an xib then pushed onto the navigationController like above, It should display correctly. Then all subsequent (second, third) controllers that are pushed will have the back button.

Comment: check the edit, make sure you do `initwithnibname`. Also, place the code above AFTER the call to initialize the window.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly add a back button.  The button will be added automatically when you push controllers into a UINavigationController.  That is, a call as:

```
[navigator pushViewController: controller animated: ...];
```

creates a back button.

Comment: say im in screen 1 with the button go to 2 and i go to screen 2, screen 2 should have the back button. where do i add that code? screen1.m on the button action or in the viewdidload of screen 2?

Comment: It will inherit the back button automatically unless you have specifically stopped it from having a navigation bar, or you have not used a push transition.

Comment: so should i replace `[self.navigationController pushViewController:menuSesionesController animated:YES];` for `[navigator pushViewController: controller animated: ...];`?

I think im not using a navigationcontroller i dont know how to use it without storyboard

Comment: Sorry.  In my answer the words 'navigator' and 'controller' are example words; you need to use the names for your controllers.

Comment: haha yeah thanks! i figured :P but do by navigator do you mean UINavigationController or UINavigationBar or what? haha sorry im kind of new to xcode